# how to get text from a listview

Tags: android, listview

my listview has two textviews. I want to get text from one of the textviews onItemclick. I have tried using the code below but this is what I get **"User@41f0a6b0"**

```
 allusers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           // TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameHolder);
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

what am I doing wrong?

my getView() method:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_listing, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.fullname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_fullname);
  convertView.setTag(holder);
 } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your getView() method ?

Comment: You are trying to convert an object to string by only using `toString`. Do you see where you are going wrong?

Comment: @ User54321 I have added my getview() method in my code please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
        allusers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameHolder);
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item: " + text + " - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item: " + text + " - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  I tried this and it's still toasting numbers yet I have text in my textview.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).getText.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The item you are trying to get is a something like a user object?
Then try something like:

```
String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).getUserName();
```

If there is a function `getUserName` in your object

Answer (score 0):

@Kamesh 
thanks sir, you helped me solve the problem. this is how I got round it:

```
  allusers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.nameHolder);
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

   User user= (User) allusers.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item: " + user.getFirstname() + " - " + i, Toast.
                        LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

you should create the TextView that you want get text from,
after that gettext from that at your setOnItemClickListener

```
     alluser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView yourgetTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourgettextviewid);
            String yourtext = bookkname.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```